# Nim: find the index of an item in an array or sequence

Tags: arrays, seq, nim-lang

Is there a builtin method to find the index of an item in an array or sequence, equivalent to Python `index` ? (It may return the index of the first occurrence, or all the indices.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's [find](https://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#find,T,S).

> Returns the first index of item in a or -1 if not found. This requires appropriate items and == operations to work.